# display only specific value of array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to display specific value of key `'pasdiz_alus'` from array `$form->data` into a table cell. And I need to display this table row only if value of key `'pasdiz_alus'` is greater than `'0'`.

The code for this is below, but the problem is that output displays also the value of key `'pasdiz_alus'` above my table row and there it is displayed as many times as number of keys of array.

How can I get rid of this display of value of " `'pasdiz_alus'` x times of number of keys in array (in my case 29 times - there are 29 keys in the array)"? In this case it is: 5454545454545454......

My code is:

```
<table style="width: 800px;">
<tbody>
<?php
if ($form->data['pasdiz_alus'] > 0){
    echo '<tr><td style="width: 100px;">Bilde šeit</td><td style="width: 500px;">  <strong>Pašdizainēts alus</strong></td>';

foreach($form->data as $key => $value) {
    if($key === 'pasdiz_alus')
    echo '<td style="width: 100px;">';
            echo $form->data['pasdiz_alus'];
        echo '</td>';
    }
      echo '<td style="width: 100px;">Cena šeit</td></tr>';
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the output display, in this case the value of `'pasdiz_alus'` is 54
The first row is the "wrong" one that I need to get rid off, and the second row is the "right" one.

```
5454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454
Bilde šeit      Pašdizainēts alus       54      Cena šeit
```

Thanks for helping!
Brgds, Raivis

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in particular with the code you've posted. Perhaps it happens earlier?

Comment: Agreed with Jack.  do a print_r($form->data) and paste it please.

Comment: is this the whole file?seems like uncommented echo or print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your script is here:

```
if($key === 'pasdiz_alus') // <-- missing opening "{"
    echo '<td style="width: 100px;">'; // <-- inside the "if"
    echo $form->data['pasdiz_alus']; // <-- OUTSIDE the "if"
    echo '</td>'; // <-- OUTSIDE the "if"
} // <-- this matches the foreach "{"
```

Why do you cycle all the array keys, instead of directly accessing it?

```
<table style="width: 800px;">
    <tbody>
    <?php if ($form->data['pasdiz_alus'] > 0) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px;">Bilde šeit</td>
            <td style="width: 500px;"><strong>Pašdizainēts alus</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 100px;"><?=$form->data['pasdiz_alus']?></td>
            <td style="width: 100px;">Cena šeit</td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This should solve your problem, but I'd recommend also to move the `if` part before even opening the table:

```
<?php if ($form->data['pasdiz_alus'] > 0) { ?>
<table style="width: 800px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px;">Bilde šeit</td>
            <td style="width: 500px;"><strong>Pašdizainēts alus</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 100px;"><?=$form->data['pasdiz_alus']?></td>
            <td style="width: 100px;">Cena šeit</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well spotted! Didnt see that missing curly

Comment: Thanks @Matteo Tassinari it works now! And thanks for explanation, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) 
{
  if($k == 'pasdiz_alus' && $v > 0) 
  {
    echo $v;
  }
}
```

you need that addition in your if to make sure its only printed if it is the right key and its greater 0